# CSS: can object-fit:cover, have a start position

Tags: html, css

I am using

```
object-fit: cover;
```

in order to have an image fill a div of a fixed size, like this

```
.home img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 650px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

However, the image is cropped equally all around, as I have text in the bottom right of the image, I want to have cover to  crop from the left and top.

Is this possible?

I tried all the object-fit methods and object-position, but none give the desired behaviour.

Comment: Can you share the working snippet

Comment: Use [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a `object-position` to the `img`, `bottom right` in this case.

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* added */
  object-position: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2880px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" />
```

Comment: Brilliant, thats exactly what I needed.